# Print Multiple HTML Tables on Separate Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, printing, html-table

I'm trying to allow a user to print multiple tables depending on what they select in the GridView. It will then select more data (from a hidden GridView) and print all the tables accordingly. What I am doing right now is taking the table at the bottom of my page, giving it a div id, and then using jJavascript to open that div in a new window. However, I'd like to be able to print multiple tables at a time, and possibly even print them on individual pages. Is there a special way to go about doing this? Some sort of special function?

Javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

//<![CDATA[
    function printContent() {
        str = document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML
        newwin = window.open('', 'printwin', 'left=20,top=30,width=600,height=400')
        newwin.document.write('<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n')
        newwin.document.write('<TITLE>Print Page</TITLE>\n')
        newwin.document.write('<script>\n')
        newwin.document.write('function chkstate(){\n')
        newwin.document.write('if(document.readyState=="complete"){\n')
        newwin.document.write('window.close()\n')
        newwin.document.write('}\n')
        newwin.document.write('else{\n')
        newwin.document.write('setTimeout("chkstate()",2000)\n')
        newwin.document.write('}\n')
        newwin.document.write('}\n')
        newwin.document.write('function print_win(){\n')
        newwin.document.write('window.print();\n')
        newwin.document.write('chkstate();\n')
        newwin.document.write('}\n')
        newwin.document.write('<\/script>\n')
        newwin.document.write('</HEAD>\n')
        newwin.document.write('<BODY onload="print_win()">\n')
        newwin.document.write(str)
        newwin.document.write('</BODY>\n')
        newwin.document.write('</HTML>\n')
        newwin.document.close()
    } //]]> 
</script>
```

How I fill my table

```
            GridViewRow row = DefaultGrid.SelectedRow;
        int rowIndex = DefaultGrid.SelectedIndex;
        HiddenGrid.SelectedIndex = rowIndex;
        GridViewRow row2 = HiddenGrid.SelectedRow;
        //int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[25].Text);
        fName = row2.Cells[0].Text;
        lName = row2.Cells[1].Text;
        addr = row2.Cells[2].Text;
        addr2 = row2.Cells[3].Text;
        city = row2.Cells[4].Text;
        state = row2.Cells[5].Text;
        zip = row2.Cells[6].Text;
        country = row2.Cells[7].Text;
        email = row2.Cells[8].Text;
        phone = row2.Cells[9].Text;
        ccType = row2.Cells[10].Text;
        ccNum = row2.Cells[11].Text;
        ccExp = row2.Cells[12].Text;
        length = row2.Cells[13].Text;
        delivery = row2.Cells[14].Text;
        price = row2.Cells[15].Text;
        source = row2.Cells[16].Text;
        joined = row2.Cells[17].Text;
        url = row2.Cells[18].Text;
        orderResults = row2.Cells[19].Text;
        pubName = row2.Cells[20].Text;
        sourceCode = row2.Cells[21].Text;
        dt = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
```

The table itself

```
<div id = 'main-content' style = "overflow: auto; height:50%; width:100%" />
    <table id="details">
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 100px;">Name: </td>
    <td><%=fName %> <%=lName %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Address: </td>
    <td><%=addr %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Address 2: </td>
    <td><%=addr2 %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>City: </td>
    <td><%=city %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>State: </td>
    <td><%=state %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Zip: </td>
    <td><%=zip %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Country: </td>
    <td><%=country %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Email: </td>
    <td><a href="mailto:<%=email %>"><%=email %></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Phone: </td>
    <td><%=phone %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CCType: </td>
    <td><%=ccType %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CCNum: </td>
    <td><%=ccNum %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CCExp: </td>
    <td><%=ccExp %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Length: </td>
    <td><%=length %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Delivery: </td>
    <td><%=delivery %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Price: </td>
    <td><%=price %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Source: </td>
    <td><%=source %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Joined: </td>
    <td><%=joined %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>URL: </td>
    <td><%=url %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>orderResults</td>
    <td><%=orderResults %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>PubName: </td>
    <td><%=pubName %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Source Code: </td>
    <td><%=sourceCode %></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Date/Time: </td>
    <td><%=dt %></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS's [`page-break-before`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-before) to print content on separate pages:

```
<table style="page-break-before: always;">
...
</table>
```

This would insert a page break before all tables.  You'll probably want to apply this to all tables after the first.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure there's a page break, use the `page-break-before: always` CSS styling on each element you want to make a page break.